# remove CR or LF or CRLF after reading file

Tags: j

In `J`, after reading in a text file, how to get rid of those `CR` or `LF` or `CRLF` and then I can use `".` without getting `spelling error`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `freads` verb will force line endings to be `LF`. If you are using J6 or earlier then you will need to load the [files script](http://www.jsoftware.com/wsvn/base8/trunk/main/main/files.ijs)  first (`load 'files'`), otherwise `freads` is available as part of the standard library. Then as Eelvex suggests [cut](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d331.htm) `;.` more specifically `;._2` can be used to divide the lines of the file using the last character in the string (in this case `LF`) as the delimiter:

```
   _99&".;._2 freads 'myfile.txt'
```

It is better to use [Numbers](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d601.htm) (dyadic `".`) to convert literals to numeric rather than [Do](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d601.htm) (monadic `".`). This avoids the potential security issue of "executing" code in the file and will correctly convert more variations, compare the following:

```
   ". '45 -34'        NB. monadic ".
11
   _99 ". '45 -34'    NB. dyadic ".
45 _34
```

You may find the following faster:

```
   _99 ". ];._2 freads 'myfile.txt'
```

`Numbers` is acting on the whole array at once rather than being run on each line individually.

Comment: Point of interest: the dyadic form of `freads` can cut the file into lines for you (using `;.` under the covers). For example, `'b' freads 'filename.ext'` puts each line into its own 'b'ox (good for irregular-length lines) and `'m' freads 'filename.ext'` does the `];._2` thing, i.e. makes a 'm'atrix of the data (which is good for regular data, like the OP's table of numbers).

Comment: but somehow, when I do that like in `/:~ (_99 ". ];._2 freads 'myfile.txt')`, I still get output `4 2 3`. Please let me know why?

Comment: Without knowing what the contents of your file are, it is hard to know what the output should be or why it is not what you expect. Are you able to show a small extract of the file you are trying to read?

Comment: the file content is `4 2 3`, plus or minus these `CR or LF or CRLF`. I cannot upload file, otherwise, it is easier

Comment: Note that `5 + _99 ". ];._2 freads 'myfile.txt'` should return `9 7 8`, so we have successfully sorted out your issue with line endings. The issue you are having now is to do with the shape of the output and how sorting works. `/:~` will sort the items in an array. The shape of the output is `1 3`. IOW you have an array of 2 dimensions (a table with 1 row/item) so sort is correctly sorting items (rows) of the table. Try `/:~ , _99". ];._2 freads 'myfile.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

`cut` [;.](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d331.htm) using the last item (fret `|2`) - which should be your CR/LF - while removing this item (fret `_2`).

```
a =: 0 : 0      NB. a =: (1!:1)<filename
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
)

*: ".;._2 a
 1  4  9 16
25 36 49 64
```

Comment: but somehow, when I do that like in /:~ (".;._2 'myfile.txt'), I still get output 4 2 3. Please let me know why?